# Как правильно сделать смену языка на сайте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть две директории на сайте, site.ru, site.ru/en

JS:

```
var language = window.navigator ? (window.navigator.language || window.navigator.systemLanguage || window.navigator.userLanguage) : "ru";
language = language.substr(0, 2).toLowerCase();
var thisLanguage = 'ru';
if(language != thisLanguage){
switch (language) {
case 'en':
window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/en';
break;
default:
break;
}
}
```

И все круто работает, но вот стал тестить (на телефоне язык системы стоит english) и такие траблы выявил:
При заходе на сайт js перекидывает меня на **site.ru/en**, но если я пытаюсь перейти на рус версию (кликнув на ссылку `<a href="/">ru</a>` - то есть переход на **site.ru**), то все равно скрипт срабатывает и редиректит меня на **site.ru/en**. Как можно исправить это недоразумение?

Comment: "Есть две директории на сайте, site.ru, site.ru/en"   Одна /en а вторая ?

Comment: @Taypfoon site.ru - первая, site.ru/en - вторая

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще так не делается, в нормальной реализации сайт один, а язык меняется через языковые файлы содержащие набор имен и соответствующих текстов, каждый язык имеет свой экземпляр такого файла, но с одинаковыми именами, например в случае с JS это может быть подгружаемый файл с переменными или массивом/объектом.

Каждая фраза подставляется обычно каким-то шаблонизатором или напрямую если он не используется. А "код" языка сохраняют в Cookie/LocalStorage/Сессиях

Но в случае вашей реализации как я понял скрипт находится на ru сайте и естественно редирект будет происходить обратно на EN, чтоб принудительно перейти вам придется при клике на RU ставить например Cookie что выключена русская версия, и проверять ее в скрипте